# Which type of project should i use for a simple Extract/Transform/Load task?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've wrote a code that runs a querie in a Database, save the result in a log file and then consume an API based on the result of the querie.

I wrote the code using a Console Application, but now that it is finished, i don't know if i should use this type of project. The code needs to run everyday, so if i would keep in a Console Application, i would use the task scheduler to run .exe that was created from the build everyday, it's going to get the job done, but i don't know if this is a good approach.

Comment: A console app being run by task scheduler sounds perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard in this case. for something so simple, if it works, you're good